Error: Nextjs 14 App Router some Image's won't get compressed / optimized
Some photos won't get compressed. Most of them get compressed to like 128kb, but sometimes some posts the images don't get compressed at all resulting in image size around 6mb and larger load times.
I would love to get some help.
Example (This image were posted like within one minute)
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have tried to see if the Image component has something to do but ended up with nothing useful, same with searching on forums and such.
